# Build asynchronous TCP client with boost

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, tcpclient

I want to make an asynchronic TCP client, using boost::asio.
I need to support methods:

```
SendData(char* buffer, int size);
GetData(char* buffer);
```

to send and get data from/to the host.

The problem is when I use async_connect - the handler is not called, even the server is up (assume I use boost tutorial server: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html )

**Client code:**

```
class TCPCommunication {
private:
    std::string m_host;
    std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> m_socket;
    bool m_initialized = false;

public:
    TCPCommunication(const std::string& host) : m_host(host) {
        if (!Init()) {
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    ~TCPCommunication() = default;

    void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error) {
        // this code is not reached!!!!!!!!!
        m_initialized = true;
        std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
    }

    bool Init() {
        try {
            boost::asio::io_service io_service;

            tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
            tcp::resolver::query query(m_host, "daytime");
            tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

            m_socket = std::make_shared<tcp::socket>(io_service);
            boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
            boost::asio::async_connect(*m_socket, endpoint_iterator, boost::bind(&TCPCommunication::handle_connect, this,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error));

            return true;
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
        return false;
    }

    int SendData(const char* buffer, int sizeOfData);
    void GetData(char* buffer);
};
```

So I can't use GetData and SendData methods.

What can be the problem in this client?

Comment: the use of a shared_ptr to hold the socket tells me that you have not started with the tutorial client in the documentation.

Comment: The tutorial client is for synchronic client, I need A-synchronic one

Comment: nonsense: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_client.cpp

Comment: The way how the example works and how I need to work is different. I need to support get and send from "outside" (i.e, tcp = new TCPCommunication(); tcp->Send("hello world"); ). The chat_client doesn't work like this.

Comment: think `new TCPCommunication(myIOService)` and initialise the socket with the io_service reference in the constructor.
You need to run the io_service of course, and make sure it does not run out of work. Did you build a work object on it?

Comment: What to you mean by "build a work object on it", and "run out of work"?

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html